# Why can't I use flyspell-mode? Error: (Searching for program No such file or directory ispell)

Tags: osx, flyspell, ispell

I am using Emacs on a macOS Monterey 12.5 with M1 hardware. This is my [init file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/edit/main/.emacs.d/init.el).

I used to use in a Linux (NixOS) machine this init file (or something very similar) without ever having a single problem with `flyspell-mode`. Now, on a new machine under macOS I am using the same init file and after trying to enable `flyspell-mode` the mini-buffer echoes:

```
(Searching for program No such file or directory ispell)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was basically installing `aspell` via brew package manager.

```bash
$ brew install aspell
```

There was no need for further configurations on the init file.