# Why does ispell generates a process?

Tags: process, flyspell, ispell, threading

After fixing `ispell` to work on a new machine running macOS ([see previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73689/why-i-cant-use-flyspell-mode-error-searching-for-program-no-such-file-or-dir)), I was surprised to see it listed as one of my processes, see the image:

[image]

As text:

```
Process.  PID.    Status. Buffer.    TTY.   Thread 
ispell    8262    run     --         --     Main   /opt/homebrew/bin/aspell -a -m -B --encoding=utf-8
```

`ispell` seems to be related to `flyspell` and I thought would be a "simple" mode. "Simply" storing a dictionary with the appropriate spelling and parsing text to find matches and misfits (indicating suggestions for the latter). I have no idea why it generates a process.

Other commands and modes do not gerate processes. I know stuff like CIDER does to watch live projects. I can't see the reason here.

Why do I have an `ispell` process running? Why is it necessary?

Comment: In my setup,  I modified the library to run a new temporary process every time the `aspell` application is used (idle timer) because I don't want an `aspell` process running 24/7.  I found certain sections in the code already set up for this; e.g., `ispell-async-processp` ....  When I made a feature request to the Emacs team, Eli Z. explained that there is overhead each time `aspell` is launched and that it learns as it goes; e.g., words to ignore, etc.  Eli Z. explained the efficiencies of having it run 24/7 and that the section of code I had zeroed in on was for systems unable to support it.

Comment: `ispell.el` calls an external program to do the checking. It looks sequentially for `aspell`, `ispell`, `hunspell` and `enchant-2`. See `ispell-init-process` and `ispell-start-process` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how ispell was originally designed. Programs that use ispell communicate with it over a pipe. The newer aspell can additionally be used as a library, which means that the aspell code runs inside the Emacs process. I am not sure if Emacs has ever been changed to use aspell that way, since that would be extra work for not much extra benefit.

Comment: Does every pipe generate a process? Is there a difference between an indefinite process (on-going process) and a task process (process is ended after task is done)? In this case, it is an ongoing process, right?

Comment: A pipe connect two processes. Emacs sends words to ispell through the pipe and ispell sends back spelling corrections. I am not sure what you mean by a “task process” though. Usually “task” and “process” are synonymous. The screenshot you included in your question indicates that ispell is still running. How else would Emacs spellcheck things if ispell were not running?

Comment: I guess the question is why the process doesn't exit but continues running. I think @lawlist's comment describes the tradeoffs well.

Comment: I see. Thank you.